# Ffmpeg to OpenGL texture black screen

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg

I am trying to make textures from ffmpeg source, but I get the black screen.

here is the code

```
avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,
            &packet);

        // Did we get a video frame?
        if(frameFinished)
        {
         f++;

                pFrameRGB=avcodec_alloc_frame();
                struct SwsContext* swsContext = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                        pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                        pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC,
                        NULL, NULL, NULL);
                if (swsContext == NULL) {
                 fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize the conversion context!\n");
                  exit(1);
                  };


                sws_scale(swsContext, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                glGenTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VideoTexture);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
 }
}

// Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
av_free_packet(&packet);
if (f>1) break;
```

Strangerly when I draw i get black screen, my video is not black.

```
if (VideoTexture != 0)
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glPushMatrix();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VideoTexture);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(Width, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(Width, Height);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, Height);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your quad is being drawn first, try changing it's color for debugging purposes. Also try checking for gl errors using `glGetError()`.

Also for using `glTexImage2D` you are passing `3` as the internal format (3rd param). This doesn't look a valid argument, try changing this to `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGBA`.

```
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
```

Should be

```
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
```

But you also have another problem: are creating a new texture object every time you are decoding a frame, if you keep creating new textures and copying new data your program will crash after a while.

I recommend you create 2 textures once and update them use `glTexSubImage2D` instead of creating new texture each time. This way each texture will as a buffer, hence emulating double buffering. This is important for flawless video rendering.

Comment: If I should initialize pFrameRGB->linesize , but with what value?

Comment: for example `width*4`. given that each pixel is 4 bytes.

Comment: pFrameRGB->linesize[0]= pCodecCtx->width*3; // in case of rgb4  one plane , no gl errors but still black picture

Comment: @user3177342 you also need to make sure of the stride sometimes its `pCodecCtx->width*3*-1`. I still don't see how line size is affecting openGL. that should be an ffmpeg problem

Comment: strange, I put the code before rendering the videoframe     // white background
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(getWidth(),0,0);
    glVertex3f(getWidth(),getHeight(),0);
    glVertex3f(0,getHeight(),0);
    glEnd();
// red square
glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(getWidth()/8, getHeight()/3, 0);
glVertex3f(getWidth()*3/8, getHeight()/3, 0);
glVertex3f(getWidth()*3/8, getHeight()*2/3, 0);
glVertex3f(getWidth()/8, getHeight()*2/3, 0);
glEnd();
videoframe size is below the whole screen size, but everything is black

Comment: @user3177342 before rendering to openGL try saving the ffmpeg frame to an image file like bmp again for debugging.

Comment: cleared up that glBindTexture doesnot make VideoTexture non zero, dont know why

Comment: I changed the code so now opengl is initialized before gen textures, do I need make some lightning to see the texture?

Comment: no need for lightning. But you need to disable it (it is by default disabled).

Comment: the texture size is 360x440, but the whole screen is black. I make  glFlush();
SwapBuffers(); after painting rexture in render screen( worked for primitive painting)

Comment: I draw white quad by the size of half screen, after texture painting everything is black

Comment: use gDebugger to make sure you are copying your texture to the GPU. that looks the problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wrote a program that decoded movies with FFMPEG and displayed them as OpenGL textures. If you want to have a look at the code, you can download it from

http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Hugh.Fisher/2dstuff/GLFFPlay.tar

Hope this helps.